# Model little cracks on the surface of an object

Tags: modeling

So I was trying to model this buddy here and I have not the slightest idea on how can I achieve the cracks on the surface of the cube's faces this thing has.

Any tip or idea on how can I do that?[[image: Blok]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to alter the physical appearance of a mesh without manually doing it (i.e using a non-destructive workflow), you would want to add certain textures that control the depth of some parts of your mesh, which is what cracks do.

There are 2 main ways to do this:

1) Using a displace modifier, which I and most other artists don't recommend unless you want to overlay it with some sort of particle-system, and

2) Giving some bump in the nodes.

---

The method we are going to explore is doing this via *nodes*. I'm not going to explain what they are; although you can read up about them [here](https://easyblend.org/html/render/blender_render/materials/nodes/introduction.html).

So, to start off with, what *are* normal and bump maps? Well, they are both used to create a fake perception of depth. *This is imperative*. ***They do not displace any actual geometry, but make it seem as if they had in render mode.*** For the purpose of this answer, I'm going to use bump maps, which convert grayscale values to depth, simply because they're easier to create procedurally.

---

Bump maps take textures like this:

[image: wall bump map]

and then convert them into depth. Generally, brighter values mean more coming-outwards and vice-versa, although it *can* be inverted. Let's get started then!

---

In the node editor, in the `normal` area of the default Principled BSDF material of the material applied to your object, add-in and plug-in a `Bump` node. Then, add a `Voronoi Texture`. This is what will control our bump values.

Change the `3D` to `4D`, and then choose `Distance To Edge`. Turn the scale down to something you like, then connect the Voronoi Texture to the `height` input of the Bump node. Check `invert` on the Bump node. Great! You have cracks now! Although they don't look like how you expected, so add in a `ColorRamp` node between the Voronoi texture and Bump node. Enable the Node Wrangler addon, and then <kbd>Ctrl Shift Click</kbd> the ColorRamp node to view it. Move the sliders around to your liking (the closer white is to the left, the less bump in the area between the cracks, and the more right the black slider is, the more outlined the cracks are).

This is where we are right now:

[image: Node Setup #1]

Here, you can end. You have achieved making cracks. However, you could still do new things, such as add colour to the cracks and stuff!

[image: Node Setup #2]

Or you could add image textures instead of flat boring colours! Go crazy.

---

*(Documentation?) links where you can learn more about these techniques*:

[Bump Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/bump.html)

[Normal Mapping Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/normal_map.html)

[Introduction to Nodes](https://easyblend.org/html/render/blender_render/materials/nodes/introduction.html)...

There's a lot. I suggest you start with those however. Hope this answer helped you!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I've been busy. I'll try this asap and give you feedback. Thanks for answering

Comment: @CarlosMediavilla No problem. Take as much time as you want.

Comment: I've been playing around with it and it seems to work perfectly wih what I want to achieve. Thank you!

Comment: @CarlosMediavilla Your welcome. Glad this was able to help you.